# How to NOT select observations from data in R

Tags: r, statistics, sample

I am doing Bagging, and I figure out the code for selecting the learning set (training).

The data set has 683 observations.

```
# data set named cancer
learningset <- cancer[sample(683,replace=TRUE),]
```

I need to get the test set, which observations have never been selected in my learning set from the original data set "cancer".

I have been trying many functions, and seems like they don't work because I can still see some of the observations exists in the learning set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can just use the `-` operator like so:

```
ind <- sample( 683 , replace = TRUE )
learningset <- cancer[ ind , ]
testset <- cancer[ - ind , ]
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I have been thinking about using " - " operator, but it never work.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `setdiff` function:

```
training.indices <- sample(683, replace=TRUE)
test.indices <- setdiff(1:683, training.indices)
```

and then:

```
learningset <- cancer[training.indices,]
testset <- cancer[test.indices,]
```

Comment: Yes, I realized later. But it helps me (and others) to filter questions that don't have an answer. Deleting my comment.